# microsoft.sharepoint.client.clientcontext does not contain a definition for 'Credentials'

Tags: 2013, 2010, web-application

I am trying to pass userid and password through the clientContext.Credentials method, but i am getting the below error

```
microsoft.sharepoint.client.clientcontext' does not contain a definition for 'credentials'
```

Below is the code snippet that i am trying to use

```
var ctx = new ClientContext("SITE URL");
ctx.Credentials = new Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SharePointOnlineCredentials("username", "password");
```

Also, I have included the below namespaces

```
using Microsoft.SharePoint;
using Microsoft.SharePoint.Client;
```

What have i missed? Why is the `.Credentials` not available?

I am using .Net version 4 for the project

Comment: have you included Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime.dll in your project?

Comment: Thanks amit, after adding that reference its working :) 
Can you please tell me what namespace should i add for Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SharePointOnlineCredentials

Comment: you can use "Microsoft.SharePoint.Client".  Reference  - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.client.sharepointonlinecredentials.aspx

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Please include Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime.dll in your project.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue but when copy that dll from SharePoint server your solution has worked but when using NuGet for getting SharePoint 15.0.0 it's not working for me even add runtime reference.

my resolution is:
add both `Microsoft.SharePoint.Client` and `Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.RunTime` as the reference.